Showing @State var in .fullScreenCover
I am trying the use a State var in a FullScreenCover view, but the variable is not getting updated. Neither the showView and selectedUUID display their values. How do I get values set in ContentView to show on the FullScreenCover view?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
        @State var showView: Bool = false
        @State var selectedUUID: UUID? = nil
        
        var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Button ("Show Full Cover")
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    selectedUUID = UUID()
                    showView = true
                }
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showView)
        {
            Text("Selected UUID: \(selectedUUID?.uuidString ?? "None")")
            Text("ShowQuotation: \(showView)")
            
            Button("Cancel")
            {
                showView = false
            }
        }
        
        .onAppear
        {
            print("FullScreenCover is displayed. showQuotation: \(showView)")
        }
    }
}

I have tried it with and without the DispatchQueue.main.async.
What am I missing?

This has been asked many times. Use .fullScreenCover(item: ...) this is what it is for. See fullScreenCover. The duplicate link shown, is old and pre-dates the advent of .fullScreenCover(item: ...)

Think of fullScreenCover like being defined statically so it doesn't have access to the latest State values if they have been changed.
